# Save a UITextField into a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an app that allows the user to create categories.  A save screen appears with a UITextField.  Although, I do not know how to save the user's entry, and allow a new UICollectionViewCell to be added into the current UICollectionView that contains the UITextField words that the user typed.  Thanks!! This is also in Swift.  This would be used in a UITableView: clothes.name = self.nameTextField.text ,but how would I convert this to a UICollectionView? **clothes is a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your collection view has a data source where you initially have the model for your cells. In your case it's probably an array. The collection view looks at this data source and returns cells based on the entries contained in this data source.

**What I am trying to get at is the following:**

In order to show the newly created cell, you'll need to update your data source (I'll call it "the blueprint specification" the collection view adheres to) by adding the new cell's "specification" (I think I'm wording this in a more complex fashion than it actually is). Here is an example (If we assume that your data source is an array):

```
categoryArray.append(CategoryModel(title: yourTextField.text)) // update the data source
```

After you make changes to the data source you can tell the collection view to reload it's data:

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

That will "parse" the data source to display the cells anew.

Let me know if anything is unclear.

### EDIT

Regarding your comment -- given that you use a `UINavigationController` -- , you can achieve displaying the title like this:

You are probably using this method to go to your next view controller:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let category = categoriesArray[indexPath.row]
    let detailVC = DetailViewController()
    detailVC.title = category.title // your title
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Alternatively, in your `DetailViewController` you can do:

```
class DetailViewController : UIViewController{

    var category : Category!

    override func viewWillAppear(){
        super.viewWillAppear()
        self.title = self.category.title

    }

}
```

Comment: How would I be able to have the textField entry show up in the navigation bar on the next page when I tap on the cell?

Comment: @SkylarBjörn updated my answer. Replaced `self.pushViewController(...)` with `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(...)`. Sorry wrote the code out of my head...